# Unxpect CORS policy error when using auth api from locally

Tags: node.js

First of all, i have an backend RESTapi running on my ubuntu server on the cloud(works perfectly 100%).

And I also have an frontend webapplication running on the same server(works perferctly aswell), and i can use the login system and all that stuff.

Now my issue: I am deploying the frontend locally at my computer for development purposes, but i still want to have the connection to my backend at the cloud instead of also deploying the backend locally.

Problem is now that when im using the authentication from my local computer i get this error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://ip-adress-to-the-backend-at-the-cloud:5000/api/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://*:3000' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The thing is: it worked perfectly logging in while using the webapp locally at my computer until last week.. Now that i made some changes in my ".env" file, "server.js" and "routes.js" file, it doesnt work.

The strange thing is that i tried removing the changes from those files but still aint working.

Here is my .env file:

```
 APP_PORT=*****
DB_HOST=*****
DB_USER=*****
DB_PASSWORD=******
DB_NAME=******
JWT_SECRET=******
JWT_KEYSECRET=*******
ALLOWED_ORIGIN=http://ipadress_to_both_the_frontend_and_backend:3000
```

here is my server.js:

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();

if(process.env.JWT_SECRET == undefined || process.env.JWT_KEYSECRET == undefined){
    console.log("Fatal error: Secret is not set")
    process.exit(1);
}


require('./startup/routes')(app)
require('./startup/database')

app.listen(process.env.APP_PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server is running: " + process.env.APP_PORT);
})
```

and my routes.js:

```
require('dotenv').config(); 
const users = require('../api/user/user.router')
const keys = require('../api/keys/keys.router')
const equipmentType = require('../api/equipmenttypes/equipmenttype.router');


const auth = require('../api/authentication/auth.router')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const express = require('express')

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(express.static('public'))

    app.use(helmet.xssFilter())
    app.use(helmet.frameguard())
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGIN);
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, x-auth-token, x-api-key');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        next();
    })

    app.use('/api/user', users)
    app.use('/api/auth', auth)
    app.use('/api/key', keys)
    app.use('/api/equipmenttypes', equipmentType)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, install cors by `npm i cors`

Add this to your server.js file:

> const cors = require("cors");

> app.use(cors());

Comment: why do i have a feeling that this wont work at all? the connection from my pc locally is still blocked

Comment: Jep, and the problem is still there. I can not access the backendAPI from local computer.

Comment: There's something called reverse proxy, you might want to look at it.

Comment: I change the line to this in my .env file :

ALLOWED_ORIGIN=*

works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple, I changed the line inse my env file this:

ALLOWED_ORIGIN=*

No, this is not a good thing to do, and not secure at all, but now i can accsess the backend api from localhost, and i can optimize my work.